# Sharing samba-folder with root access

Tags: 10.10, server, mount, samba, share

I have a staging server in my network running Ubuntu server 10.10, being my main development area. As I need to access the files in the Apache root from other computers in the network, I have setup samba with the following settings:

```
[www]
    comment = Apache root www
    path = /var/www
    writable = yes
    force user = root
    force group = root
```

On the host computer, running Ubuntu 10.10 desktop, I am trying to mount the drive with a bash file looking like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.5/www /media/www/ -o username=myusername,password=mypassword,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

What happens is that I get *mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)* thrown in my face whilst trying to execute the mount.

I've done exactly the same, with exactly the same smb.conf & mount-bash file on another computer in my network, but this just wont work.

What am I doing wrong? I am running out of ideas.

Comment: If someone wonders, I've run `smbd restart` after editing the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file...

Comment: Did you check samba logs on server side (`/var/log/samba/smbd.log` or similar)?

Comment: Yep - checked the log and the only thing that appears in the log is "`[2011/02/27 14:16:53.770717,  0] printing/print_cups.c:108(cups_connect) Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused`" which I guess isn't related

Comment: Security in the `smb.conf` is set to user, if anyone cares

Comment: Well yes, CUPS message shouldn't relate to that in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic troubleshooting:

1. Connect with `smbclient -U myusername //192.168.1.5/www` and see what happens
2. Do same from server (not from remote host)
3. Check `/var/log/samba/smbd.log` and `/var/log/samba/log.[remote address]`
4. Increase samba logging level and retry. You can do this by adding `log level = 3` to your `smb.conf` (and either restarting or sending HUP to smbd).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Olli. I was able to try out `smbclient` as shown in your answer and found out that a "NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE" were thrown. I ran `sudo smbpasswd -a myuser` and everything worked out after a `smbd restart`! Thanks a lot!